# Laravel Validation of Required With

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm attempting to set up validation for my request in my controller and I'm trying to figure out how I can have address, city, state, zip all depend on each other as far as if there's a value for one then there must be a value for all of them, address2 is the only one that is stand-alone but depends ONLY on the address. For some reason, this doesn't work. For example, if the city is submitted then validation passes. So I don't quite understand what I"m doing wrong.

```
'address' => 'required_with_all:city,state,zip|string|nullable',
'address2' => 'required_with:address|string|nullable',
'city' => 'required_with_all:address,state,zip|string|nullable',
'state' => 'required_with_all:address,city,zip|string|size:2|nullable',
'zip' => 'required_with_all:address,city,state|integer|digits:5|nullable'
```

Answer (score 19):

`required_with` and `required_with_all` don't work in the way you're interpreting them. `required_with_all` means this field is required if **all of the following fields** have values. For example, `required_with_all:address,state,zip` means "city is required if address and state and zip all have values".

You're trying to achieve:

- If `address` has a value, `city`, `state` and `zip` are required
- If `address2` has a value, `address` is required
- If `city` has a value, `address`, `state` and `zip` are required
- If `state` has a value, `address`, `city` and `zip` are required
- If `zip` has a value, `address`, `city` and `state` are required

The rule you're looking for then *is* `required_with` but the logic is different. You can effectively use the `required_with` rule by anchoring on one field, e.g: anchor against `address` and your rule in English can be "if `address` has a value, then city, state and zip are required, or if `city`, `state` or `zip` have a value then `address` is required" which can be constructed as:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'address' => 'required_with:city,state,zip|string|nullable',
    'city' => 'required_with:address|string|nullable',
    'state' => 'required_with:address|string|size:2|nullable',
    'zip' => 'required_with:address|integer|digits:5|nullable'
]);
```

And for `address2` your rule is "`address` is required if `address2` has a value" (which will cascade into causing `state`, `city` and `zip` to be required too). This is again constructed using `required_with`, we set `required_with` on `address`:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'address' => 'required_with:city,state,zip,address2|string|nullable',
    'address2' => 'string|nullable',
    'city' => 'required_with:address|string|nullable',
    'state' => 'required_with:address|string|size:2|nullable',
    'zip' => 'required_with:address|integer|digits:5|nullable'
]);
```

Edit: there was an error in a previous version of this answer, it is now fixed.